# creating account by data from spreadsheet - google apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

I am working on a simple script that creates an account in the control panel of a domain - for example Gmail - and I was looking for a function in the Google apps script that creates an account automatically on inserting data to a spreadsheet

I searched the internet and I did find this though : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_usermanager
and the method I am using is : `var user = UserManager.createUser("john.smith", "John", "Smith", "password`
My question is, how can I insert the parameters from the spreadsheet that I have.
Sorry if this sounds a bit stupid I'm just new to Google apps script.

Comment: while you are busy with that script, use the same data to compose a email message to send to the newly created users with their password and usernames (send it to their 'old' email of course). You could also add them to groups if necessary... all those things so easily automated with GAS ! Isn't life beautiful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from the spreadsheet, you would use the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet).

An example of reading a set of rows. (Let's say all rows).

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

`.getValues()` returns a 2D array. So you would access it by `data[rowNum][colNum]`. Let's say you want to add every row as a new user, you could do

```
for (var i in data) {
  UserManager.createUser(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3]);
}
```

How would you run said script? You could put all of it inside some function (`function addAllUsers()`) and then run it from the run menu in the Script Editor.